# Can this question be reopened?

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions, specific-question, duplicate-questions

This [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/174733/is-wrapping-a-third-party-code-the-only-solution-to-unit-test-its-consumers) was closed for being an exact duplicate, but I modified it extensively so that it now discusses  a particular condition to wrapping third party code.

In its previous condition the question was too generic and may have been indeed a duplicate.

Comment: In the future, don't remove the "duplicate of" link, even if you've made edits. It'll make it easier to find what it was originally considered a duplicate of and determine if it's different enough.

Comment: @ThomasOwens sorry for that, will be more careful next time.